# Qt as unity's UI

Tags: qt, unity-game-engine, user-interface, embed

I saw that genshin impact (made with unity) has qt/qml folder so I suppose the whole game's UI is made with the QT core.
I tried to look up how to add qt to unity but I didn't find anything relevant (apart from the unity scene widget from the qt core but I don't think that's it).

So has anyone got an idea how they achieved it (if they actually did) ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i'm aware, it's not possible to create UI using Qt core with Unity. So the qt/qml folder you saw was probably for something else and doesn't mean they used Qt.